# Xamarin.Forms - accessing Android Assets and iOS Resources from PCL

Tags: xamarin.forms, resources, assets

I want to avoid having things like API keys hard-coded in variables, and so am going to store them in a file which is read into variables at runtime.

In Android this will be a file under Assets, and in iOS it will be a file under Resources.

Is there a library I can use in the PCL to retrieve an asset from the current OS? I can't remember seeing one!

If not, I've got no problem creating my own simple interface with platform-specific implementations, but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why not just create a class that has the keys and such as constants and then call the class wherever you need it?

Comment: Because this can easily be decompiled and the keys are then visible.

Comment: Doesnt the PCL just get compiled with the App archive? So someone would have to decompile the app archive in order to see that? And if you sign it that would be very difficult to do no?